# Commit exists on GitHub but not in my local clone

Tags: git, github

I accidentally pushed a commit with sensitive data to Github. So I immediately deleted the branch that contained the commit (via Github UI). When I recloned the repo and run `git show <hash>`, I received `fatal: bad object <hash>`, so I know that commit is gone, but when I visited `github.com/$account/$repository/commit/<hash>`, I can still see the commit.

I saw this solution. 
https://help.github.com/articles/commit-exists-on-github-but-not-in-my-local-clone/
But I am unable to implement for my case because I no longer keep the repo with the branch that has the commit locally, and none of my collaborator does. What can I do to delete this commit from Github page/UI?

Comment: Related: [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Comment: Just clone the repository from github again, and you should have the bad commit again locally. You can do this in a new folder. then follow linked questions.

Comment: The commit is actually orphaned because it is not merged and the branch that contained it has been deleted. So when I cloned it again, the commit was not cloned in the local repository, it is only accessible via Github UI page `github.com/$account/$repository/commit/<hash>`. Will the garbage collector clean up the orphaned commit?